# C++ - 10 most popular colors of a bitmap

Tags: c++, bitmap

I am working on a C++ project - it is supposed to find height, width and 10 most popular colors of a bitmap. Finding height and width is not a problem, I've done it within minutes, but I have serious problems with finding these colors.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream plik;
    plik.open(argv[1]);

    if (plik.good())
    {
        cout << "Bitmapa zaladowana poprawnie." << endl;


        // Idziemy do 10 bajtu w pliku - tam jest zapisany numer bajtu pod ktorym zaczynaja sie informacje o pixelach
        plik.seekg(10, ios::beg);
        int adresPixeli = 0;
        plik.read((char*)&adresPixeli, sizeof(int));

        // Idziemy na 18 bajt w pliku (pod nim jest zapisana szerokosc, a od 22 jest wysokosc)
        plik.seekg(18, ios::beg);
        int szerokosc, wysokosc;

        // Zapisujemy szerokosc do zmiennej szerokosc (w pixelach)
        plik.read((char*)&szerokosc, sizeof(int));

        plik.read((char*)&wysokosc, sizeof(int));

        cout << "Szerokosc obrazu to: " << szerokosc << endl;
        cout << "Wysokosc obrazu to: " << wysokosc << endl;

        // Przejscie na 28 bajt w pliku, pod nim jest zapisana informacja o tym ile bitow ma kazdy pixel
        plik.seekg(28, ios::beg);
        int iloscBitow = 0;
        // Read number of bytes used per pixel
        plik.read((char*)&iloscBitow, sizeof(short int));



        // Jesli mamy wysokosc i szerokosc to mozemy stworzyc tablice ktora bedzie przechowywac wartosci kolorow pixeli
        // Rozmiar tablicy musi byc rowny szerokosc * wysokosc, a jeden pixel ma 3 bajty informacji
        // RGB - red green blue, czyli informacje o kolorach (po 1 bajcie na red, green i blue) 

        // Alokacja pamieci dla tablicy ktora bedzie przechowywac wartosci bitow.
        int *mapaPixeli = new int [szerokosc * wysokosc];

        // Przejście do bajtu pod ktorym zaczynaja sie pixele
        plik.seekg(adresPixeli, ios::beg);

        // Zmienna do ktorej bedziemy wczytywac wartosc pixela (kolor - RGB, zapisany szesnastkowo np. 0xFFFFFF to kolor bialy, a
        // 0x000000 to kolor czarny
        // pozniej policzymy najczesciej wystepujace kolory i je wypiszemy
        int wartoscPixela;
        for (int i = 0; i < szerokosc * wysokosc; i++)
        {
            wartoscPixela = 0;
            // Wczytujemy 3 bajty - bo na tylu zapisane sa informacje odnosnie 1 pixela, do zmiennej wartoscPixela
            plik.read((char*)&wartoscPixela, 3);
            // Zapisujemy wartosc w tablicy pixeli
            if (iloscBitow == 24)
            mapaPixeli[i] = wartoscPixela;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            cout <<  hex << mapaPixeli[i] << " ";


        // Szukanie 10 najpopularniejszych kolorow

        int max_count = 0;
        int wynik;
        // Przechowuje te elementy ktore juz zostaly policzone
        vector<int> wartosciUnikalne;
        // Sprawdza, czy element jest juz w wektorze wartosciUnikalne
        bool czyJest = find(wartosciUnikalne.begin(), wartosciUnikalne.end(), 1) != wartosciUnikalne.end();
        // Sprawdza czy wypisano juz 10 kolorow
        int ileKolorow = 0;

        cout << "Kody szesnastkowe 10 najpopularniejszych kolorow w bitmapie: to" << endl;

        // Bedziemy wyliczac wystepowania 10 najczesciej powtarzajaych sie elementow
        for (int ilosc = 0; ilosc < 10; ilosc++)
        {
            int max_count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < szerokosc*wysokosc; i++)
            {
                // Sprawdza czy element jest w wartosciUnikalne
                czyJest = find(wartosciUnikalne.begin(), wartosciUnikalne.end(), mapaPixeli[i]) != wartosciUnikalne.end();
                int count = 1;
                // Jesli nie ma elementu w wartosciUnikalne - liczy jego wystapienia
                if (czyJest == false)
                {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j<szerokosc*wysokosc; j++)
                    if (mapaPixeli[i] == mapaPixeli[j])
                        count++;
                    if (count>max_count)
                        max_count = count;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < szerokosc*wysokosc; i++)
            {
                int count = 1;
                czyJest = find(wartosciUnikalne.begin(), wartosciUnikalne.end(), mapaPixeli[i]) != wartosciUnikalne.end();

                // Sprawdza czy jest element w wartosci unikalne, jesli nie ma - szuka aktualnie sprawdzanego elementu o najwiekszej
                // ilosci wystapien i wypisuje go
                if (czyJest == false)
                {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < szerokosc*wysokosc; j++)
                    if (mapaPixeli[i] == mapaPixeli[j])
                        count++;

                    if (count == max_count && ileKolorow <=10)
                    {
                        ileKolorow++;
                        wynik = mapaPixeli[i];
                        cout << hex << wynik << endl;

                        //cout << count << " " << max_count << endl;
                        wartosciUnikalne.push_back(wynik);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else
        cout << "Nie udalo sie wczytac bitmapy." << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

This line:

```
plik.read((char*)&adresPixeli, sizeof(int));
```

Is supposed to write an address of pixels to adresPixeli. It is at 10th byte , so before that I just go to 10th byte of file here:

```
plik.seekg(10, ios::beg);
```

And here I want to read the values into an array called mapaPixeli which has enough memory (width * height).

```
for (int i = 0; i < szerokosc * wysokosc; i++)
        {
            wartoscPixela = 0;
            // Wczytujemy 3 bajty - bo na tylu zapisane sa informacje odnosnie 1 pixela, do zmiennej wartoscPixela
            plik.read((char*)&wartoscPixela, 3);
            // Zapisujemy wartosc w tablicy pixeli
            if (iloscBitow == 24)
            mapaPixeli[i] = wartoscPixela;
        }
```

The problem is: it doesn't read values properly :( I don't know why and I can't find a bug. Maybe some of you will be able to help me there. Also there is a condition - it will only read pixel if it's 24 bits (1 pixel is 24 bits in my case), checked it.

Then after that there is my own algorithm for finding 10 most popular values in an array, which works perfectly, but here it doesn't work as I would like it to, because pixel values are not being read properly.

Comment: I think you are hugely underestimate the complexity of the bmp file format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format. can you use an external library to access to the pixels?

Comment: No I can not use any external library. That's the problem :s yeah I read that page on the wiki before. I know it's pretty complex but I have to do it somehow.

Comment: You will going to be lost if you rush you code without thinking a little about it. Create a proper class, read the file header with appropriate structure, store information in member variables, split your code into separate logical units (different functions), etc. As AlessandroTeruzzi said, it is not so a trivial thing.

Comment: I know, but the thing is it is not a project for me but for my friend who studies electrotechnics (I study CS), I dunno why they are supposed to create such projects... Really don't know what's the point. And he is not interested in programming really, so I want to do it as simple as possible, without using classes (because then it will be harder for him to defend). I am just looking for a proper way to read pixel info (RGB) into an array, because my code works for 1 bitmap but for other 3 it doesn't, which is suprising.

Comment: @MindRoller This is not surprising. There are a lot of bmp formats: with or without compression (that changes everything), with or without own colors map, etc. If your code must work on **every** bmp file, I am sorry but you cannot do that in just few days, like that. If you want your code work on simple bmp files, I've done a very simple code that write images with shade of grey. You can get inspiration from it : https://github.com/Boiethios/libfdvcpp/tree/master/Misc .

Comment: Thanks, my program works correctly for simple bitmaps (with like 3 colors let's say) but for more complex - with let's say 8 colors it doesn't. Doesn't read bytes properly, it does read it fine for one, but doesn't for another, so as you say I will not be getting into it any deeper. That's all I needed.

Comment: 1 more thing guys: can you recommend me any external library for such a project like this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot about the padding at the end of each line in the bitmap image as shown on this picture: 
[image]

You need to skip this padding when processing the bitmap. I suggest replacing this cycle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < szerokosc * wysokosc; i++) {
  ...
}
```

with two nested cycles and seeking in the file before processing each line:

```
    int wartoscPixela;
    int bytesPerPixel = 3;
    int padding = szerokosc * bytesPerPixel % 4 == 0 ? 0 : 4 - szerokosc * bytesPerPixel % 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < szerokosc; i++)
    {
        plik.seekg(adresPixeli + (szerokosc*bytesPerPixel+padding)*i, ios::beg);
        for (int j = 0; j < wysokosc; j++)
        {
            wartoscPixela = 0;
            // Wczytujemy 3 bajty - bo na tylu zapisane sa informacje odnosnie 1 pixela, do zmiennej wartoscPixela
            plik.read((char*)&wartoscPixela, 3);
            // Zapisujemy wartosc w tablicy pixeli
            if (iloscBitow == 24)
                mapaPixeli[i*szerokosc+j] = wartoscPixela;
        }
    }
```

Before the cycles you calculate the padding and put it into a variable:

```
int padding = szerokosc * bytesPerPixel % 4 == 0 ? 0 : 4 - szerokosc * bytesPerPixel % 4;
```

Then before each line you move the file stream pointer to the beginning of each line:

```
plik.seekg(adresPixeli + (szerokosc*bytesPerPixel+padding)*i, ios::beg);
```

This code assumes that BMP file in question has 3 bytes per pixels. If it has a different color depth, you need to modify your code accordingly.

Comment: That's a good point, +1, tried that, program works better but still not properly :/

Comment: Well it's really strange because it should work... ehh damnit, it calculates the first color correctly (bitmap has 2 colors) but second is not correct it says 6363 instead of 006363.

Comment: Okay I corrected everything and it works now! Thanks @Reilly :) best answer is here!